# How to save UIImage to file with NSFileManager?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

How I can save UIImage to file with NSFileManager ?

Thank,

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here we go.

This will store a `UIImage` into your documents directory of your iOS App.
You won't need `NSFileManager`.

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

UIImage * imageToSave = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

[binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.png"] atomically:YES];
```

**Edit:**
If you store images form the iOS Camera, you might look at how you can rotate the images to the right orientation. [Look here in that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358559/uiimagepngrepresentation-writetofile-is-always-landscape).

Comment: Thanks but when I load the image it shown me with wrong orientation.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli ... that's why I suggested NSCoding.

Comment: @Matisse VerDuyn: okay. one plus. But turning it by "hand" is not that hard. :)

Comment: how do i retrieve the file?

Comment: @user1234096 `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` strips `imageOrientation`

Answer (score 1):

To save it as a file, you'll either need to put it in a plist, or create a png/jpg representation of the image. You can save the UIImage data a little easier with NSCoding.

See this tutorial for more info: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager

Comment: Hmm... why use NSCoding? Okay: maybe when you try to store complex object structures with UIImages in it. The coding process also eats CPU ticks.