# How to save programmatically captured screenshots into a folder and compress it?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to save programmatically captured screenshots into folder and compress it. Is that possible? Someone help

Answer (score 2):

Step one - create screenshot: [How to take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

Second - save it: [How to save UIImage to file with NSFileManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094195/how-to-save-uiimage-to-file-with-nsfilemanager)

Third - zip it. You can use zlib wrapper [objective-zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/)

EDITED: here is some code from objective-zip embedded sample:

```
    ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:filePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Adding first file..." waitUntilDone:YES];
    ZipWriteStream *stream1= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"abc.txt" fileDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400.0] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Writing to first file's stream..." waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSString *text= @"abc";
    [stream1 writeData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Closing first file's stream..." waitUntilDone:YES];
    [stream1 finishedWriting];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Adding second file..." waitUntilDone:YES];

    ZipWriteStream *stream2= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"x/y/z/xyz.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Writing to second file's stream..." waitUntilDone:YES];
    NSString *text2= @"XYZ";
    [stream2 writeData:[text2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Closing second file's stream..." waitUntilDone:YES];
    [stream2 finishedWriting];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(log:) withObject:@"Closing zip file..." waitUntilDone:YES];

    [zipFile close];
    [zipFile release];
```