# Saving images from an array to a file in filemanager

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have been working with nsfilemanager and trying to save images as files where the images are obtained from an array. But i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save UIImage to file with NSFileManager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094195/how-to-save-uiimage-to-file-with-nsfilemanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save an image, you can do the following :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f)];
[data writeToFile:theDesiredPath atomically:YES]);
```

So if you want to save the images contained into your array, simply iterate your array with a for statement and call theses two lines of code...

For example :

```
for (UIImage *img in arrayOfImages){
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0f)];
    [data writeToFile:theDesiredPath atomically:YES]);
}
```

Comment: ok. that one worked. and files are created. but when I try to retrieve those images to a imageview, nothing is showing up.-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([flowernamearray count]!=0)
    {
      
        NSString *imagepath=[flowernamearray objectAtIndex:row];
        UIImage *image;
        image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath];
        imgvw.image=image;

       
    }
}

Comment: This code seems correct. Try to set a breakpoint to see if `imgvw` is nil, check if `imagePath` is really a valid path. Otherwise, create another thread to explain precisely the problem you're encountering.