# When I save image to file the orientation that save is wrong

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, xcode4

When I save image to file it save with wrong orientation .

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image:(NSString *)imageName
{
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);         
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];   
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];         
   NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];
   [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try saving as a jpeg instead:

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);

If you need to save it as a PNG, check this discussion:
[UIImagePNGRepresentation ..... writeToFile is always landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358559/uiimagepngrepresentation-writetofile-is-always-landscape)